# Store the current user in a field of a django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to find the way of store the user who creates an object and I want to do it automatically. I've found some things but nothing works for me. Here is the code:

Models.py:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    ...
    usuari = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Forms.py:

```
class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Track
```

Views.py

```
def pujar_track(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    formulari = TrackForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formulari.is_valid():                    
        formulari.save()                    
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/inici')
else:
    formulari = TrackForm()

return render(request,'principal/trackForm.html',
    {'formulari':formulari})
```

I've seen about put:

```
usuari = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, editable=False) but
```

But I don't know when can I set the user in the field.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 3):

You can hide `usuari` from your `TrackForm`, so the user can't select it:

```
class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        exclude = ('usuari',)
```

And then, replace your `formulari.save()` with:

```
track = formulari.save(commit=False)
track.user = request.user
track.save()
```

This is a common use case and detailed in the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Comment: I'm sorry if this is an easy work, I am really new with django... Now I get the following error:

null value in column "usuari_id" violates not-null constraint.

I tasted with usuari = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True) 

but the same happends

Comment: That probably means that `request.user` is `None`, i.e. no user is logged in. Read the docs about the `login_required` decorator.

Comment: That's not the problem. The user is logged... Nevertheless thanks for your help!