# Django models: user ID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm currently building a helpdesk ticketing system as a school project. I am using the built in django auth system, and I'd like to refer to user IDs from the auth sytem. For example, a ticket will be assigned to a certain helpdesk employee. A part of my model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    submitter = #reference to user
    assignedTo = #reference to helpdesk employee
```

Users are in the group `user`, helpdesk employees are in the group `helpdeskemployee` of the django auth system.

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173245/django-built-in-user-model-implementation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074869/store-the-current-user-in-a-field-of-a-django-model)

So I tried this:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    submitter = models.OneToOneField(User)
    assignedTo = user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

But that gives the folowing error while running `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
deskman.ticket: Accessor for field 'submitter' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'submitter'.
deskman.ticket: Reverse query name for field 'submitter' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'submitter'.
deskman.ticket: Accessor for field 'assignedTo' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'assignedTo'.
deskman.ticket: Reverse query name for field 'assignedTo' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'assignedTo'.
deskman.ticket: Accessor for field 'assignedTo' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'assignedTo'.
deskman.ticket: Reverse query name for field 'assignedTo' clashes with related field 'User.ticket'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'assignedTo'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you probably don't want to use a `OneToOneField`. That would imply that a user can only ever have one single ticket. A `ForeignKey` relationship would be better.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    assignedTo = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The reason you are getting an error is that you have two relationships to the same model from your `Ticket`. This means if you have a `User` object and you are trying to reverse it, it's not clear via which relationship you want to use:

```
 user.ticket_set.all() 
 # Do you want `submitter` tickets, or `assignedTo` tickets? It's not clear
```

To fix it, add a `related_name` attribute to each field

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="tickets_submitter")
    assignedTo = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="tickets_assignedto")
```

Now you can get both reverse relationship separately:

```
 user.tickets_submitter.all()
 user.tickets_assignedto.all()
```

Comment: could you explain how works `assignedTo = user = ... `?

Comment: oops, typo. Fixed now